# npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - Unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided

Tags: github, github-actions, publish, github-enterprise, github-packages

I am new to GitHub and I have created a ACTIONS in GitHub Enterprise 3.7 to publish the package to GitHub Package.
But the job failed with log as below:
[image]

I have setup the Repository Token as shown below:
[image]

The value of Token I have retrieved from here [image]
and assign to value for REPOSITORY secret NPM_TOKEN [image]

However, it just said the TOKEN cannot be authenticate. Any idea where I doing wrong?

*****Add on** - The ACTIONS will run success if I assign the TOKEN value where I get from my GitHub Access token (Setup in GitHub.com but not GitHub Enterprise), ACTION will run success. However, the published package will only show in my GitHub but not in my GitHub Enterprise.
[image]
[image]

GitHub Enterprise Account will not able to see that Published Package.
[image]